# Reading %s by using %s crashes

Tags: c++, string, text

I'm making a chat thing and when somebody enteres "%s" or "%s%s%s" everybody's client crashes, heres kinda how i do it.

```
const char* pszID = their id
const char* pszName = their name
const char* pszChatText = their raw message

if (!pszID || !pszName || !pszChatText)
return;

std::string strChat;
strChat.append("[");
strChat += pszID;
strChat.append(" :: ");
strChat += pszName;
strChat.append("] ");
strChat += pszChatText;

SendToServer(strChat.c_str());
```

so if they enter %s%s%s
the pszChatText is %s%s%s and crashes.

but i want it to do it normally like,

```
[A48AJV :: thegamerman3000032] %s%s%s
```

and sendtoserver is the one crashing, it's just a printf() of a const char*, i also check if its a null pointer

EDIT: fixed for guidelines

Comment: If the client crashes when it receives the message, the bug is in the client receiving the message. The code you pasted has nothing to do with a client handling receiving a message.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're passing the string directly into `printf` as the first argument. Don't do this. This is because the first argument is parsed for placeholders. If you specify more placeholders than variadic arguments then your program will crash.

Instead provide `"%s"` as the first argument and your string as the second.

For example:

```
string chatMessage = "makeItCrash%s%s%s";
printf( "%s", chatMessage ); // program will not crash now
```

Comment: tried it using `"%s", strPushToConsole.c_str()` and without the `c_str()` but still crashes when someone does %s as their message, could it be the += i do?